# Is distance traveled still counted?

Tags: pokemon-go

In Pokemon Go is the distance traveled still measured and counted towards eggs whilst you are in a battle or have a prompt on screen?

For example. With the new "I'm a passenger"  prompt coming up randomly whilst I'm walking for to gps wander.

Comment: You have the 'I'm a passenger' prompt while walking? Calm down Sonic the Hedgehog

Comment: I don't have the answer but I have noticed that while catching Pokémon in a car, after you return to the main map screen your avatar will be shown running very fast in a straight line the entire distance from where the Pokémon was to where you are now. My guess is this means it wasn't tracking my position and sees my location as jumping instantly. I have no evidence exactly what it's doing though.

Comment: @fredy31 it does it whilst I'm at my desk too!

Comment: I get that message while I'm walking too. I'm guessing it's due to the location jumping suddenly, but who knows for sure.

Comment: since there is no real answer yet I will do some testing at some point, but it may not be accurate due to being such a small test.

Answer (score 1):

It will count, but you will have to be  going under 20 kmh or 12 mph.

Comment: Do you have a source for this information?

Comment: @JAL I have tried it myself and it does work, so unless my experience doesn't count as a source, I do not have a source.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all movement should count towards egg hatching that isn't too fast. That being said, a number of people did some experiments and seemed to find that the major reason for discrepancies between recorded distance and how far one actually walked was that if the game was loading information from the server, the distance was not counted. MEaning that anytime the little "loading" symbol appears in the corner, chances are good that your movement is not being counted towards your incubating eggs. Whenever the person testing this stopped walking whenever they saw the "loading" symbol and waited for the symbol to disappear before continuing to walk, they found that the distance applied to the egg was the same as the distance they walked. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Silph Road Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4x8vc3/egg_hatching_speed_105_kmh_with_science/),

> **Distance logging is not impacted by**
>
> - Having a pokestop selected on your screen
> - Having a different egg hatch mid walk. I'm referring to the screen with a picture of an egg that says "Oh?"
> - Having your menu open while walking. I was on the egg selection screen for testing. What is interesting is that the distance values don't actually update until you close the screen and reopen it, but the distance logged was correct.
> - CATCHING A POKEMON. I'm very excited to report this as it's been speculated for a long time that catching a pokemon while walking won't log your location correctly. That is wrong. I entered a battle/cutscene whatever you want to call it prior to walking. Didn't interact with it for the entire 1 km. At the end I caught 2 of the pokemon and ran from the other two. All four attempts gave me full distance logging.

As mentioned in the answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286829/does-walking-distance-count-if-you-are-also-capturing-a-pokemon), this should apply to the distance logged when using a buddy, as well.

Basically, as long as you are traveling less than 10.5 km/h and the app is open on your device, the distance will be logged.